# Writing a command-line tool in VimScript

Tags: vimscript

I am going to write a program which can be run from the command line, at least on *nix systems.  I considered using Python or Perl, but why not Vimscript?

**Has anybody done this?**

**What is the best practice for writing this kind of application?**

**Is there a bootstrap or library?**

User interaction will be minimal in my case. The input will be provided as arguments to the executable, and Vim will display text output and do some processing.

---

---

### My initial attempt

Outputs this when run:

```
$ ./my_new_app arg1 "broken word" arg3

Retrieved arguments: arg1 broken word arg3
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Argument 0 is: arg1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Argument 1 is: broken
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Argument 2 is: word
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Argument 3 is: arg3
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

There are three issues:

1. It breaks the second argument into **two arguments** due to the space.
2. Every time I print something, I must **Press ENTER**.
3. If I pipe the result as in `./myapp 1 2 3 > output.file` then I get **"Warning: Output is not to a terminal"**, and I can't see the Press ENTER prompts, although I still need to fulfil them.

#### *my_new_app* (executable file)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pass the arguments to Vim in a variable, and exec my_new_app.vim
vim -c ":let g:arguments_string='$*'" -c ":so $0.vim"
```

#### *my_new_app.vim*

```
function! s:Print(str)
  exec '!echo "' . a:str . '"'
  " This doesn't work so well: I only see the first line.
  "call system('echo "' . a:str . '"')
endfunction

call s:Print("Retrieved arguments: " . g:arguments_string)

let s:args = split(g:arguments_string, ' ')

for i in range(0, len(s:args))
  call s:Print("Argument " . i . " is: " . s:args[i])
endfor

exit
```

Comment: [One of my tools](https://bitbucket.org/Carpetsmoker/password-bunny/src/ca2199b79aa7c053690726993549e30dc6b2d02f/pwbunny?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) does this by pre-processing the arguments in a shell script, rather than VimScript. I don't know if this works well for your specific use-case, but it certainly saves you from re-implementing `getopt` in VimScript...

Comment: Much as I love vim, it is a text editor, not a true scripting language.  The best hydraulic cutting machine in the world still makes a poor three-ring hole punch.

Comment: You probably don't want to use VimL as a general-purpose scripting language.  It's orders of magnitude slower than Python and Perl, and the API has a lot of limitations that make it unsuitable for many tasks.

Comment: @Wildcard Please make that an answer!